# Upload a <img> to server without going through canvas?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, file-upload, plupload

It would concern images which have their src pointing to other domains or as file://. (user pasting html code into tinymce)

Basically:

- I have to do this client side (can't download from server)
- I only need to support firefox
- I'm using javascript and html5 and if possible plupload

I'm worried that canvas only returns raw pixel data and that the original compression of the image gets lost.

It just seems wrong to make a second copy in memory and then convert it to data:// to upload a file the browser already has in memory. (by the way base64 data is usually a lot bigger than binary)

I am hoping it would be possible to tell firefox to upload a file from it's memory cache or use the FileReader or Blob functionality.

**edit: if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10755011) is correct, it won't even work cross-domain with canvas.**

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, this is impossible due to security limitations preventing javascript from accessing any data that has come from another domain.

It looks like I would have to write a firefox addon in order to enable this. Not quite the same level of service if users have to install an addon though.

Answer (score -1):

**you can use  other domains using don not use src image filed use upload manger to this

you can use other way by put .** `<img src = '/*url*/' ></img>`