# Convert image from image control to byte[] asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, byte

I have an asp image control as following:

```
<asp:Image ID="imagenSubida" runat="server" style="max-height:400px" />
```

now I want to convert the image that is stored inside that control into a byte array so that it can be stored into data base. The thing is I don't know how to make the conversion. Any help will be much apreciated.

Comment: http://www.morgantechspace.com/2013/11/Convert-Image-to-Byte-Array-and-Byte-Array-to-Image-in-csharp.html

Comment: Do you want to perform the conversion at post? Is the image physically stored into your directory?

Comment: Hi, the image is just stored on the image control, using this code:                       imagenRes.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String; imagenRes refers to the image control and the url was obtained from a byte array.

Comment: I think you need something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754661/javascript-getting-imagedata-without-canvas