# Extract image out of a list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a `ul` with `li` of images. I am taking the last `li` and want to extract the image data from it to upload, other wise the server (Flask) tells me that the data is an `HTMLLIElement`.

So how do I got about this? Here's the JS code:

```
        // e.preventDefault(e);
        var img = new FormData();
        img.append('file',$("#preview_list li:last-child")[0]);

        // Debugging statement
        //$("#preview_list li:last-child").dialog();
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "/_process",
            data : img,
            contentType: false,
            dataType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR) {
                alert(data['result']);
            }
        });
```

Comment: you should add one example of a `<li>`, just to be sure how they are built

Comment: I found this nifty technique here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754661/javascript-getting-imagedata-without-canvas . But at the moment it only looks like a workaround.