# Download <img>s without using their URL

Tags: javascript, blob

It is straightforward to download `<img>`s by downloading to their URLs. When the URLs became unaccessible, the images can still be seen on the monitor and right-click copy to clipboard, though can't do right-click save-as.

At this moment, is it possible to save the images to disk with JavaScript? (without using the mouse, certainly)

There are these kind of `<img>`s for testing on https://www.sunday-webry.com/viewer.php?chapter_id=3101, in which all `blob:...` images became immediately unaccessible, and even the speediest developers are not able to catch them.

The code is only expected to be run under the newest version of the state-of-the-art browsers.

Comment: Seems possible via canvas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-url-in-javascript    testing ...

Comment: Success!! But be careful, the top answers using `width` and `height` instead of `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` may result in cropped images. Also I am wondering maybe there are methods without using canvas, since this extra process may make the image of less quality.

Comment: Maybe related: [getting ImageData without canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754661/javascript-getting-imagedata-without-canvas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to via canvas (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58653042/8535456):

```
Object.defineProperty
(
    HTMLImageElement.prototype,'toDataURL',
    {enumerable:false,configurable:false,writable:false,value:function(m,q)
    {
        let c=document.createElement('canvas');
        c.width=this.naturalWidth; c.height=this.naturalHeight;
        c.getContext('2d').drawImage(this,0,0); return c.toDataURL(m,q);
    }}
);
```

Without modifing the property (https://stackoverflow.com/a/934925/8535456):

```
function getBase64Image(img) {
    // Create an empty canvas element
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.naturalWidth
    canvas.height = img.aturalHeight

    // Copy the image contents to the canvas
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    // Get the data-URL formatted image
    // Firefox supports PNG and JPEG. You could check img.src to
    // guess the original format, but be aware the using "image/jpg"
    // will re-encode the image.
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

Notes that `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` are used instead of `width` and `height`, since the latter results into cropped images when the image is attributed or styled with fixed sizes.

However, by printing the picture to the canvas, the quality may decrease. I am wondering if there are methods that can get the images directly from the memory.